# Django with Select2 remote data example

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, jquery-select2

I have a model (let's call it `Animal`) that has a `ForeignKey` to a `Genus` model. I would like to have a `Modelform` that allows the user to select an Animal instance.  Clearly, there are too many animals for a single select list so I would like the user to be able to filter by genus and then search by animal.

[Select2](https://select2.github.io) has [an example of using Ajax request](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) to do something oh-so-similar to what I want.  Instead of searching for a *usr/repo*, I would search for a *genus/animal*. The user might not know the exact genus or the exact animal they want, so both bits need to be searchable. This UI is fine for my needs.

[Django-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) allows me to use [Select2](https://select2.github.io) with Django and has a [widget](http://django-select2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django_select2.html#django_select2.forms.HeavySelect2Widget) that I think I should be able to use. Note that `urls.py` contains a `url(r'^heavy_data/$', heavy_data, name='heavy_data'),` so I can access the view method fine.

In my `ModelForm`'s `__init__(...)`, have:

```
self.fields['animal'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    widget=HeavySelect2Widget(data_view='heavy_data'),
    queryset=Animal.objects.all())
```

And in the `views`:

```
def heavy_data(request):
    filtered_animals = {}
    if request.is_ajax():
        import ipdb
        ipdb.set_trace()
        # What next?
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(filtered_animals))
```

I am unsure how to pass the whole `genus/animal` search string form the form to the view. However, I might not even be on the right tracks... Am I? Is there a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually trivial.

First define a new widget like so:

```
class MyWidget(ModelSelect2Widget):
    search_fields = ['name__icontains', 'genus__name__icontains']
```

Then, in your form, use that widget:

```
class AnimalModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['animal', ]
        widgets = {'configurator': MyWidget, }
```

You can then search either by genus, animal, or both. There is no clever formatting, you just type search terms.

Many thanks to [Johannes Hoppe](https://github.com/codingjoe) for [his help](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/issues/257).